# Python: After raising argparse.ArgumentError, argparse raises generic error

Tags: python, regex, assert, argparse

I defined a custom regex type for an argument that needs to follow an exact format. I used code from another post ([regex custom type](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/argparse-users/tAC1eH1a29c)) that has been super useful. My problem is that I'm writing unit tests where I expect the regex to fail and trying to assert that the `argparse.ArgumentError` is raised ( `assertRaises(argparse.ArgumentError, parser.parse_args(inargs.split()))` ). The problem is that argparse appears to be catching the ArgumentError and throwing a generic error, preventing me from verifying the cause of the failure. Am I missing something?

Here is the traceback:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markebbert/PyCharmProjects/newproject/unittests.py", line 203, in test_set_operation_parameter
    self.assertRaises(argparse.ArgumentError, parser.parse_args(inargs.split()))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1688, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1727, in parse_known_args
self.error(str(err))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2347, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2335, in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2
```

Here is my defined custom type and the parser code:

```
class RegexValidator(object):
    """
    Performs regular expression match on value.
    If match fails an ArgumentError is raised
    """

    def __init__(self, pattern, statement=None):
        self.pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        self.statement = statement
        if not self.statement:
            self.statement = "must match pattern %s" % self.pattern

    def __call__(self, string):
        match = self.pattern.search(string)
        if not match:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(None, self.statement)
        return string


operatorRV = RegexValidator(
    "^((\w+)=)?[iIuUcC]\[(\w+(\[\w+(,\w+)*\])?)(:\w+(\[\w+(,\w+)*\])?)*\]$",
    "Set operations must conform to...")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Compare variants across individuals',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

group.add_argument('-s', '--set-operation', dest='operation', nargs='+',
                   type=operatorRV,
                   help="blah.")
```

Here is the unit test:

```
    # Fail for ending colon
    inargs = "-s out=i[one[id1]:]"
    self.assertRaises(argparse.ArgumentError, parser.parse_args(inargs.split()))
```

Comment: Argparse raises a `SystemExit`, because that is what a command line tool is supposed to do; return a system exit code on error.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I would not consider argparse a command line tool since it is a python module. As with any module, I would expect to be able to "catch" argparse's errors and handle them myself.

Comment: It is a library to *build* command line tools. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argparse is a command line parser, and errors always end up calling `argparse.exit()`, which in turn calls `sys.exit()` with an error code. This is by design.

For a unit test, you'd have to monkeypatch (using mocking perhaps) the `.error()` or the `.exit()` methods of the parser. `.error()` is called with an error message and prints the usage message, then calls `.exit()` with an exit code and the error message.

Their current implementations:

```
# ===============
# Exiting methods
# ===============
def exit(self, status=0, message=None):
    if message:
        self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
    _sys.exit(status)

def error(self, message):
    """error(message: string)

    Prints a usage message incorporating the message to stderr and
    exits.

    If you override this in a subclass, it should not return -- it
    should either exit or raise an exception.
    """
    self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
    self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
```