# how to make python argparse to accept not declared argument

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script that receives online arguments using `argparse`, like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--local", action="store_true", help=("Write outputs to local disk.")
)

parser.add_argument(
    "--swe", action="store_true", help=("Indicates 'staging' environment.")
)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I want `argparse` to handle undeclared arguments and just to add them to the arguments dictionary, but it raises an error when I try `python runner.py --local true --swe true --undeclared_argument this_is_a_test`:

```
runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --undeclared_argument this_is_a_test
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get argparse.ArgumentParser.parse\_args() not to exit on argument errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004901/is-there-any-way-to-get-argparse-argumentparser-parse-args-not-to-exit-on-argu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python argparse ignore unrecognised arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818146/python-argparse-ignore-unrecognised-arguments)